# When my user authenticated my objects turn it right but if its unauthenticated my objects turn false. How can I fix it?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have productDetails function and it gives me a products details and also if user authenticated, it can bookmark the products. But when I open the projectDetail page if I unauthenticated, my product object turn false how can I fix that ? Unauthenticated users can see products but cannot bookmarking

```php
public function productDetails($slug, Product $product)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $product->load(['user.products' => function ($q) {
        $q->take(15);
    }, 'brand', 'color', 'size', 'images', 'category.products' => function ($q) {
        $q->inRandomOrder()->take(15);
    }]);
    $similarProducts = $product->category->products()->limit(10)->get();
    $similarArr = array();
    foreach ($similarProducts as $similarProduct) {
        $similarProduct = $this->userProductLikeAndBookmark($user, $similarProduct);
        $similarArr[] = $similarProduct;
    }
    $userProducts = $product->user->products;
    $productArr = array();
    foreach ($userProducts as $userProduct) {
        $userProduct = $this->userProductLikeAndBookmark($user, $userProduct);
        $productArr[] = $userProduct;
    }
    dd($productArr);
    $product = $this->userProductLikeAndBookmark($user, $product);
    return view('home.pages.detail', compact('product', 'similarArr', 'productArr'));
}
```

Comment: please explain more clearly.

Comment: İf user unauthenticated I cannot view the products because my products objects turn false. So I want if user authenticated , they can bookmark the products but if unauthenticated they can see the products but wont able for bookmaring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```php
$user = Auth::user();
$product = $this->userProductLikeAndBookmark($user, $product);
```

When unauthenticated, `$user` is null and therefor whataver `userProductLikeAndBookmark` function in your controller is doing, it's not accepting `null` as a first argument as `$user`

Possible solution:

```php
if (auth()->check()) {
  $product = $this->userProductLikeAndBookmark($user, $product);
}
return view('home.pages.detail', compact('product', 'similarArr', 'productArr'));
```

#### the product would be returned as is (not liked or bookmarked) from the RouteModelBinding method injection if user is unauthenticated